# python sh git.diff('HEAD') blocks

Tags: python, git

The following script blocks:

```
from sh import git 
git.diff('HEAD')
```

If I interrupt I get the following traceback:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    git.diff('HEAD')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 726, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 291, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 295, in wait
    self._handle_exit_code(self.process.wait())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1096, in wait
    pid, exit_code = os.wait
```

However, *git.branch()* works nicely. So what do I need to do in order to get the git diff output with python sh?

Python v.2.7
Git v.1.7.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `git diff` output exceeds a screen (don't remember exactly, ~48 lines), `git diff` waits fou you to press `q` to exit or other key to continue with `:` prompt.

As pointed out @phobic in comments, one can use `--no-pager` git option to prevent output pagination.

For general cases when command waits on user input, one can implement interaction processing, alike one in [tutorial](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/tutorials/2-interacting_with_processes.html).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of this problem. You can work around this with the --no-pager flag, so that output goes straight to stdout: print git('--no-pager', 'diff')